# Alternative for two sequentially executed loops with identical ranges

Tags: c#

For the moment I'm executing my code as follows:

```
foreach (int data in dataList)
{
    PreProcess(data);
}
foreach (int data in dataList)
{
    Process(data);
}
```

First I have to loop over some data (from a list) and to do some pre-processing after which then I do have to loop again over the **same** data list and do some processing, but those loops have to be run one after another, and **cannot** be merged as follows...

```
foreach (int data in dataList)
{
    PreProcess(data);
    Process(data); // Cannot be run in the same loop with PreProcess(data);
}
```

...because `PreProcess(data)` and `Process(data)` are logging a lot of information which could be interlaced in case both are looping together.

---

The only alternative I've found will be using Linq, but still has the same duplicate `ForEach`:

```
dataList.ForEach(data => { PreProcess(data); });
dataList.ForEach(data => { Process(data); });
```

---

Is there any way to rewrite this in order to remove the redundancy for two loops with same range, but still looping sequentially first over `PreProcess(data)` and `Process(data)` afterwards?

Comment: Why don't you like using two loops? If there is no other way then there isn't. To me it looks more like an xy-problem where you are trying to _optimize_ the looping instead of telling us what the real problem is, this is, why you cannot process your data at the same time with a single loop. Without this information this question severely lacks context and should be closed.

Comment: Few words about codereview's community: if you have questions like "how to do something?" better do not ask here, only working solutions are discussed here. You can simply rephrase your post in order to avoid such questions.

Comment: @t3chb0t: this is an overly simplified example of my real production code. I do not know how to explain or abstract it better, but I'm just using very often identical loops (more than 2) and wanted to know if there is a better approach than the normal one, and have less repeating foreach declarations. I do not see any other "core"-problem in my context than redundancy and the wish to redefine loop range in one place.

Comment: @t3chb0t: sorry I've did not managed to edit the comment in time and adding the information you requested (also added it in the question): PreProcess(data) and Process(data) are logging a lot of information which could be interlaced in case both are looping together.

Comment: @outoftime: thanks for the feedback and I will rephrase it accordingly. Do you think that Stackoverflow would have been a better place for this?

Comment: I think SO would as bad as any other community because you are not telling us anything about the real problem. You don't want to _optimize_ any of these loops because it doesn't make any sense without knowing anything about what they are for and if you are using them for logging then most likely is your logging logic that needs to be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also define something like

```
private void MyLoop<T>(Action<T> action, IEnumerable<T> dataList) 
{
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        action(data);
    }
}
```

and use it

```
MyLoop(Process, dataList);
```

or using Action

```
Action<Action<int>> myLoop= action =>
{
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        action(data);
    }
};
```

and use it like this

```
myLoop(Process);
```

Answer (score 1):

## First Class Collection

The First Class Collection is an idea of the [Object Calisthenics](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf).

> Any class that contains a collection should contain no other member variables. Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to the collection have a home.

We can wrap `dataList` into its own class

```cs
class DataList 
{

    private List<int> list;

    // ...
}
```

## [Feature Envy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/feature-envy)

> A method accesses the data of another object more than its own data.

Since the collection `dataList` could be wrapped into its own class and gets modified by `PreProcess` and `Process` you have an Feature Envy.

We could put the methods `PreProcess` and `Process` into the class `DataList`

```cs
class DataList 
{

    private List<Data> list;

    public void PreProcess() 
    {
         /* ... */     
    } 

    public void Process() 
    {
         /* ... */ 
    } 
}
```

Now when you call it from the outside you simple call the methods

```cs
dataList.PreProcess();
dataList.Process();
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
interface IActionStrategy
{
    void applyTo(RequiredDataType data);
}
// ...
foreach (IActionStrategy strategy in strategyQueue)
    foreach (RequiredDataType data in dataList)
        strategy.applyTo(data);
```

Each strategy have to implement common interface in order to do it.